# Why is mup failing to deploy my meteor application

Tags: ubuntu, meteor, digital-ocean, meteor-up

Ive created a Digital Ocean image and setup [mup](https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up#setting-up-a-server) as detailed in [this](http://johngibby.com/blog/How_to_deploy_your_meteor.js_app_on_Digital_Ocean) tutorial. In the setup file I have my app set to the root directory of where the meteor project is located `/Users/dereck/Documents/Meteor/myapp/` for some reason when I try to deploy the app using `mup deploy` I get he following error

```
Package this project up for deployment. The output is a directory with several
build artifacts:

- a tarball that includes everything necessary to run the application server
  (see README in the tarball for details)
- an unassigned apk bundle and a project source if Android is targeted as a
  mobile platform
- a directory with an Xcode project source if iOS is targeted as a mobile
  platform


Options:
  --debug        build in debug mode (don't minify, etc)
  --directory    output a directory (rather than a tarball) for the
                 application server bundle. If the output location exists,
                 it will be recursively deleted first.
  --settings     set optional data for Meteor.settings for the build-time
                 settings (such as settings required by Cordova plugins).


=> Build Error. Check the logs printed above.
```

I don't really see what the error is, and i have no idea how to fix it. The only thing I thought of is that it wants the .meteor folder instead of the root folder, but when I tried that it still didn't work.